# react-data-grid cannot implement row grouping - possible addons issue as well

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-data-grid

I'm using [react-data-grid](https://github.com/adazzle/react-data-grid) and I have not really managed to get the [row grouping](http://adazzle.github.io/react-data-grid/examples.html#/grouping) functionality to work.
I cannot get pass the toolbar configuration, but even if I comment this out (I actually don't want to show the toolbar because I want by default some columns grouped and that's it, but still) I still cannot get this to work.

So, first things first, addons are installed:

```
yarn add react-data-grid
yarn add react-data-grid-addons
```

First error is about my `CustomToolbar` component (which is pretty much copied from the example)

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Element type is invalid: expected a
string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for 
composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to 
export your component from the file it's defined in. Check the 
render method of `CustomToolbar`.
```

But my CustomToolbar looks ok, apart from the fact that it uses components from the `addons` repo:

```
import React from 'react';
import {ToolsPanel} from 'react-data-grid-addons';

const {Toolbar, GroupedColumnsPanel} = ToolsPanel;    

const CustomToolbar = ({groupBy, onColumnGroupAdded, onColumnGroupDeleted}) => {
    return (<Toolbar>
      <GroupedColumnsPanel 
        groupBy={groupBy} 
        onColumnGroupAdded={onColumnGroupAdded} 
        onColumnGroupDeleted={onColumnGroupDeleted}
      />
    </Toolbar>
  );
};

export default CustomToolbar;
```

I used the `react-data-grid-addons/README.md` as a reference for the imports, but I'm not really sure if it's updated, judging by the documentation of the repo.

If I comment the `toolbar` property out I get the same error for `HeaderRow` component, which is again one of the repo's components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to import the AdvancedToolbar, not the Toolbar.

Check the [example source code](http://adazzle.github.io/react-data-grid/scripts/example21-grouping.js)

```
const {
  ToolsPanel: { AdvancedToolbar: Toolbar, GroupedColumnsPanel },
  Data: { Selectors },
  Draggable: { Container: DraggableContainer },
  Formatters: { ImageFormatter }
} = require('react-data-grid-addons');
```

It is importing the AdvancedToolbar, not the Toolbar component. Also if you check [the export for the ToolsPanel](https://github.com/adazzle/react-data-grid/blob/master/packages/react-data-grid-addons/src/toolbars/index.js) you can see that there isn't any component called `Toolbar` being exported, that is why you get the error in the render method.

Comment: Great, that's the help I needed! ES5 named imports confused me. Thank you, it works now!